# python-openstacksdk user and tenant creation (create user, create project and allocate quota)

Tags: python, sdk, openstack

I want to use python API to create a User and project, assign that user to the project created and then allocate certain quota. I can't find documentation for this. What is the best way to do these tasks using code (cant do it with CLI).

Thanks.

Error :  'Proxy' object has no attribute 'v2'

Code:

```
from openstack import connection
import openstack

conn = connection.Connection(auth_url="https://example.com/v2.0",
                             project_name="admin",
                             username="admin",
                             password="test", verify=False)


conn.identity.v2._proxy.create_role()
```

Documentation URL : https://developer.openstack.org/sdks/python/openstacksdk/users/proxies/identity_v2.html

Comment: `conn.identity.v2._proxy.Proxy.create_role() `, not yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried openstack user/domain/project creation using python directly. But the openstack cli in turn uses the python APIs only.

The CLI command actually imports the python module 'openstackclient'.

So digging further into this may help you.

The default location where openstack client installed is

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openstackclient/

Comment: I want to build a middleware (service layer) which does it for me. I need to have python APIs which creates accounts for me.

Comment: My understanding is, you need to create your own python api which creates users etc., If you are allowed to call CLI commands internally, then try using system calls in python. Your API will be just a handler/parser between the python API caller and openstack CLI. Your API should do all pre-configs like exporting ENVs

Comment: Yes, I ll create my API..but I need to use openstack sdk to create users. I am creating a middleware between a UI and openstack.

Comment: Using CLI from Python is wht I can do, but I would prefer openstack APIs or SDK